# How can I model a variable current sink in spice?

Tags: simulation, current-source

For a project I am working on ([related question here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101961/how-do-i-increase-multiply-the-value-of-a-current-sink)) I need to model a nonideal variable current sink in spice.

Simply reversing the orientation of a current source or inverting its value is not sufficient because it is still sourcing current, just in another direction.

I am fairly certain there is a 'trick' using some built in components to simulate a variable resistance since as far as I understand, that may be the most accurate model for this component.

Comment: "Simply reversing the orientation of a current source or inverting its value is not sufficient because it is still sourcing current, just in another direction." ... In that case, you're going to have to tell us what *your* definition of "current sink" is, since it clearly isn't anything related to the conventional definition.

Comment: I mean something along the lines of these current sinks http://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/telligent-evolution-components-attachments/00-18-00-00-00-15-61-11/Precision-Current-Sink.JPG It does not provide any power, unlike the spice current source.

Comment: And it's not necessarily true that a SPICE current source provides power to a circuit. Depending on the voltage across the current source it may provide power, absorb power, or do neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a current sink that can't drive a node below ground, just add an ideal diode as a voltage clamp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxTDBt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I'm going to try this in my simulation then finalize the question/answer. For the other part of my question, I suppose you just make it a dependent or parametric current source, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.